# Open pop-up message window on click of save button ,while uploading documents

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript

I wish to populate message on click of save button when we are uploading documents to document library.

I need to do something with `editForm.aspx` page but I'm not able to reach there.

[image]

How can I do this using javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your `EditForm.aspx` and put the below code inside a **Script editor web part**.

> My suggest is that you should put your code in text file & load it to
>   Script Editor webpart

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var j = jQuery.noConflict(); 
 function PreSaveAction() { 
 var txtTitle = j(":input[title='Title']").val(); 
   alert(txtTitle);
   if(txtTitle == ''){        
   alert("Please enter a title");          
   return false;
}
else{
   return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

**Note:-** This is the sample code, If your title is blank and you click on the Save button then it will show the alert.

Comment: Is a function named `PreSaveAction` the key part here?

Comment: Yes it is calling when you click on save button on any of the form before saving the content to list.

Answer (score 3):

First, disable the form to open in pop up window.
Next, Edit the page and add content editor web part to the page referring to a .txt or javascript file.

last step is to use form presave action method to add your javascript to show an alert message.

See here, how to use PreSaveAction: https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/create-sharepoint-sub-site-using-jquery-javascript-client-object-model-in-sharepoint-2016/